# Верстка адаптивных блоков

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Необходимо разместить три блока таким образом, как на картинке с помощью `flexbox`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        <div class="ask_us">
            <div class="items">
                <div class="item vk">
                    <p>Задайте нам вопрос в VK. Мы расскажем подробности партнерской программы.</p>
                    <a href="#">Задать вопрос</a>
                </div>
                <div class="item email">
                    <p>Не сможете быть онлайн? <span>Получите запись вебинара </span>на почту или в VK</p>
                    <a href="#">Получить запись</a>
                </div>
                <div class="item other">
                    <p>Хотите, чтобы мы оповестили Вас о вебинаре любым другим способом?</p>
                    <a href="#">Оставить заявку</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  width: calc((100% - 40px) / 2);
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ask_us">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item vk">
      <p>Задайте нам вопрос в VK. Мы расскажем подробности партнерской программы.</p>
      <a href="#">Задать вопрос</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item email">
      <p>Не сможете быть онлайн? <span>Получите запись вебинара </span>на почту или в VK</p>
      <a href="#">Получить запись</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item other">
      <p>Хотите, чтобы мы оповестили Вас о вебинаре любым другим способом?</p>
      <a href="#">Оставить заявку</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  max-width:svoi variant;
  flex-basis:300px;/*пространство за которое боряться элементы, каждый эелемент будет занимать себе 400пикс, это я к примеру, там подбирать можно, но не задавай в процентах только*/
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display:
}
```

```html
<div class="ask_us">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item vk">
      <p>Задайте нам вопрос в VK. Мы расскажем подробности партнерской программы.</p>
      <a href="#">Задать вопрос</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item email">
      <p>Не сможете быть онлайн? <span>Получите запись вебинара </span>на почту или в VK</p>
      <a href="#">Получить запись</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item other">
      <p>Хотите, чтобы мы оповестили Вас о вебинаре любым другим способом?</p>
      <a href="#">Оставить заявку</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```